# MongoDB 2 node cluster

Tags: replication, failover, mongodb-3.2

I am trying to understand the implications of setting up a 2 node MongoDB cluster with the following configuration (Documentation does say a minimum of 3 nodes is required).

MongoDB Version is 3.2.

If I configure both nodes with `"arbiterOnly": false`, and set Node1 with `Priority: 2` and Node2 with `Priority: 1`, in case Node1 goes down, won't Node2 take over? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Because MongoDB automatic failover works election system. When the election system wants to decide a new primary node, it needs a qualified majority from secondary nodes or arbiter.

If you want to run a replica set of just two nodes, you should use the arbiter. The arbiter node resource cheaper than the other nodes.

Check out PSA in the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-three-members/).

Priority means;

> The value of the member’s priority setting determines the member’s
> priority in elections. The higher the number, the higher the priority.

Imagine, running with 3 nodes replica set, one of them going down, and the other two nodes hast to decide a new primary. When they doing that check out their priority.

> The priority settings of replica set members affect both the timing
> and the outcome of elections for primary. Higher-priority members are
> more likely to call elections, and are more likely to win. Use this
> setting to ensure that some members are more likely to become primary
> and that others can never become primary.

Otherwise, you should take a look at this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-secondary-only-replica-set-member/).